# How do I render the new route of a child resource into the application sidebar outlet?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, outlet

My project is ember.js using ember-cli and ES6 import methods.

This question is about rendering the `new` route for the child resource `dataset` into the application `{{ outlet 'sidebar' }}` while other routes on dataset (show) render into `{{ outlet 'main' }}`

**application.hbs**

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
  Outlet Main
  {{liquid-outlet "main"}}
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  Outlet Sidebar
 {{liquid-outlet "sidebar"}}
</div>
```

**router.js**

```
this.resource('organizations', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.resource('organization', { path: '/:organization_id' }, function() {
      this.route('edit');
      this.resource('datasets', function() {
        this.route('new');
        this.resource('dataset', { path: '/:dataset_id' }, function() {
          this.route('edit');
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

**routes/organization.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    //render into application so organizations template doesn't show
    this.render('organization', {
      into: 'application',
      outlet: 'main',
      controller: 'organization'
    });
    // **** Not working but roughly what I want to do
    this.render('organization.datasets.new', {
      into: 'application',
      outlet: 'sidebar',
      controller: 'organization.datasets.new'
    });
    // ******
  }
});
```

Currently I get this error when attempting this code:

```
Error while processing route: types.index You passed `controller: 'organization.datasets.new'` into the `render` method, but no such controller could be found. Error: You passed `controller: 'organization.datasets.new'` into the `render` method, but no such controller could be found.
```

My understanding is that any child resource routes should be determined in the parents route. True? 
How do I get ember to recognize the controller? I'm guessing my syntax is wrong...
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
this.render('organization/datasets/new', {
  into: 'application',
  outlet: 'sidebar',
  controller: 'organization/datasets/new'
});
```

Use "/" instead of ".".

Answer (score 0):

In terms of pure syntax, what I was doing wrong is specifying `organization.datasets.new` rather than just `datasets.new`. The `this.resources` creates a new namespace so you don't need to specify organization. Turns out  `this.resource` is being deprecated in favor of `this.route` anyways.

As far as actually doing what I want to do, I'm going to have to flatten my routes. Will post better answer when I figure out a flat hierarchy that works the way I want.